# While-loop not working in my C program

Tags: c

Just making a  simple while loop to find the ASCII value of a letter, and made a loop however there is something that stops it from looping. Beginner to coding so I'm a bit lost!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char Num, again;

    again = 'A';
    while (again == 'A')
    {
        printf("\nEnter letter");
        scanf("%c", &Num);
        printf("\nThe ASCII value of %c is %d\n", Num, Num);

        printf("\n\nEnter A to look up another");
        printf("\nor any other letter to quit");
        scanf("%c", &again);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your `main()` have a return type?

Comment: What is the output? in which scenario the loop terminates?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`) & `valgrind`. Read also the documentation of the functions that you are using, e.g. [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Take the habit of *ending* not starting your `printf` format with `\n` (because `stdout` is often *line buffered*)

Answer (score 4):

Simple let `scanf()` ignore the `'\n'` which  is captured by the `"%c"` specifier, like this

```
scanf(" %c", &again);
```

Also, you should do it for the other `scanf()` otherwise, every loop will print the `'\n'` character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space before `%c` to consume the `\n`:

```
scanf(" %c", &again);
```

Here is an alternative algorithm (using non-standard `getch()` function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int letter;
    printf("Enter letters or <ESC> to stop:\n");

    while((letter = getch()) != 27) {
        printf("The ASCII value of %c is %d\n", letter, letter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this would not be portable `getch()` is not a standard function. And you didn't even include the necessary header.